# Unable to allocate 35.1 GiB for an array with shape (31316, 224, 224, 3) and data type float64

Tags: python, tensorflow, memory-management

I am trying to train my CNN with a training dataset with 30,000 images. I believe I know what the error is, that my laptop doesn't have enough memory to handle all the data but what would be the solution to this? The datatype is uint8 when I check it, but the error has float64

Preprocessing Code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
import cv2

class_list = open("Class List", "r")
CATEGORIES = []
number = 1

for line in class_list:
    line = line.strip()
    CATEGORIES.append(line)
class_list.close()

DATADIR = r'C:\Users\steel\Downloads\Datasets\225 Bird Species\images'
for category in CATEGORIES:
     path = os.path.join(DATADIR, category)
     for img in os.listdir(path):
         img_array = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path, img), cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

DATADIR = r'C:\Users\steel\Downloads\Datasets\225 Bird Species\train'
training_data = []
def format_training_data():
    for category in CATEGORIES:
        path = os.path.join(DATADIR, category)
        class_num = CATEGORIES.index(category)
        for img in os.listdir(path):
            try:
                img_array = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path,img), cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
                training_data.append([img_array, class_num])
            except Exception as e:
                pass

format_training_data()
print(len(training_data))
import random
random.shuffle(training_data)


X = []
y = []

for features, label in training_data:
    X.append(features)
    y.append(label)

X = np.array(X).reshape(-1, 224, 224, 3)
y = np.array(y)

import pickle

pickle_out = open("X_SciFair.pickle", "wb")
pickle.dump(X, pickle_out)
pickle_out.close()

pickle_out = open("y_SciFair.pickle", "wb")
pickle.dump(y, pickle_out)
pickle_out.close()
```

Where the Error Occurs:

```
X = pickle.load(open('X_SciFair.pickle', 'rb'))
y = pickle.load(open('y_SciFair.pickle', 'rb'))

X = X / 255.0 <--
```

My laptop has 8gb of RAM but usually only 5 or so is free at any given moment, and I'm pretty sure I can't add more.
If you need more information to answer, I'll try to add it

PS I tried to change the array dtype to 'float16' but it changed it to float32 which is still to large(12.3 GiB)

Comment: You mentioned the dtype is `float32`; however, I tried `cv2.imread` and it returns `uint8` dtype. Can you check what is the value of `img_array.dtype`?

Comment: The base dtype is uint8 when I check, and when it is actually called upon, the error message shows float64. That is why I tried float16 and float32, but only float32 works

Comment: So, try casting it back to `uint8`. That should work theoretically. If you want to calculate the size of the array in memory; it would be `30,000 x 224 x 224 x 3 bytes` (if `uint8` is used), this is equal to `~4.3 GB`. One other thing to keep an eye at is the `X = np.array(x)..` call, the problem with this call is that it creates a **new** array, meaning that `x` still exists in memory. This will lead to using double the amount of memory needed.

Comment: So, I realized that I had left out where the error actually occurred. I saved my arrays with pickle so I wouldn't have to preprocess it again. That means that the original X is not using any RAM because that was in a separate program. Also, reverting it to 'uint8' does nothing because to divide the array it needs to use a float datatype. I am thinking if I use a for loop to divide each value separately instead of all at once, it might work. I'll get back to this tomorrow

Comment: if you need to operate with uint8 - try X = X // 255. But it may still requre 8.6 GB (4.3 * 2). I would avoid loading the whole dataset into memory